# Console Interface Navigation Button Listener - java

Tags: java, button, console

I'm writting a console interface for a small program I'm doing. I display something like this on the console:

```
Please select:
1)Add user
2)Delete user
3)Edit user
```

The method it self should listen for a button push, and if that button push is one of the digits 1,2 or 3 it should call some other method and clear all the text from the console. Something like this:

```
display the above info
if(button is not pushed)
   do nothing
else if ( button == 1)
    call method addUser and clear everything on the console, so that addUser
    can display it's info
```

I know the question does not contain any code, but I have no idea how to do this. I know there should be some kind of button listener, but have no idea what to use and how. Any help is welcomed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add an event listener to the button(s), and when that specific button is clicked, you call the required methods.

If you're not familiar with event listeners, I strongly suggest you check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html and related pages on the official documentation portal.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This code can guide you to your solution. Use `BufferedReader` to read from console and check codes for buttons which was pressed, and depending on them, call the appropiate methods.

```
 public static void main  (String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Hit 1, 2 or 3");
        int buttonCode = bufferRead.read();
        System.out.println("Code of button hit is: "+buttonCode);
        //Button Codes for 1, 2 and 3 keys are 49, 50 and 51 respectively

        if (buttonCode==49) {
            //DO insert user
        } else if(buttonCode==50) {
            //Do delete
        } else if (buttonCode==51) {
            //Do Edit
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong button pressed");
        }
    }
```